# Multiprocessing with Python and Caffe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, caffe, pycaffe

I have a pretrained caffe model and I'm trying to make a prediction with it. However, I am trying to perform this prediction in a separate process using python's multiprocessing module so as to not slow down the main program. However, the process seems to freeze when trying to make the prediction. Is this possible with caffe? If not, are there other methods to do efficient parallel processing with caffe in python?

Here's a simplified version of my code

```
def predict(pretrained_network, data):
    prediction = pretrained_network.predict([data])
    return prediction

#Main Program

#Network loaded here 

while True:
    #Grab data
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=predict, args=(pretrained_network, data))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    #Do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process images in batch mode using pycaffe. This is much faster than processing image one by one.
You can examine the code of pycaffe classifier class
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py#L89
for details.

Comment: I have the images coming in via a video stream so batch processing is not an option. Is there a way to do this with python's multiprocessing module?